# TransactionTooLargeException when opening pick image intent (Kotlin, Android)

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm currently working on my app, and I have a fragment where the user can pick an image to insert into a database. This works, but when I go on my edit fragment and try to use the same code again to pick an image, I get an `TransactionTooLargeException`.

### Error

```
2020-12-26 23:23:45.919 3837-3837/com.google.gradient.red E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.google.gradient.red, PID: 3837
    java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 7007624 bytes
        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:161)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:888)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
     Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 7007624 bytes
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:526)
        at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityTaskManager.java:4561)
        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:145)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:888) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
```

### What I've tried

I saw some solutions saying to put something like this into my code that triggers with the image intent, but I still get the same error. I might be doing something wrong, but I'm not sure.

```kotlin
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.clear()
    }
```

### Code

Here is my `OnCreateView` where I set the setOnClickListener:

```kotlin
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_update, container, false)

        // Set menu
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        // Get bitmap
        bitmap = args.currentItem.image

        view.current_title_et.setText(args.currentItem.title)
        view.current_description_et.setText(args.currentItem.description)
        view.current_mood_spinner.setSelection(mSharedViewModel.parseMood(args.currentItem.mood))
        view.current_mood_spinner.onItemSelectedListener = mSharedViewModel.listener

        // Opens gallery when image button clicked, gets image
        view.current_image_et.setOnClickListener {
            readStorageTask()
            //Intent to pick image
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
            intent.type = "image/*"
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1001)
        }

        return view
    }
```

I'm trying to make it so that users can edit images in my app and don't know how I would solve this bug, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `readStorageTask()` ?

Comment: @blackapps Thanks for your comment! `readStorageTask()` is just my function to check if the app has permissions, ask for them if not, etc. I tried removing it and testing again, but nothing changed.

Comment: One more thing is that this issue only seems to occur when I'm trying to edit an entry that doesn't already have an image. If I'm editing an image that has null as its image value, I can add an image successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue as I was switching my code to use ViewModel. It was working fine before, not sure if that had an impact but here's how I fixed it.

doing `outState.clear()` fixed the crash, but of course is not ideal as it clears all the outState for me also made it so I couldn't process the images.

So I used `outState.keySet()` in  loop and printed each key. Then put `outState.remove(key)` for each key, and commented out each key 1 at a time until I found the one that caused the crash. For me it was "android:support:fragments".

I'm assuming this is because I was launching the gallery from the fragment, and also calling `onActivityResult()` from the fragment. So the only thing I needed to remove from the outState was `outState.remove("android:support:fragments")`, this just meant I needed to launch the gallery intent from the activity, and process it from there too.

It's still not an ideal fix as I'm sure I'm causing more problems by removing the fragments outstate, but it's a good temporary fix for now, I will update when I have time to research more into it, or maybe someone who is more familiar with the lifecycle in ViewModels that can find a better solution.

TL;DR:

add `outState.remove("android:support:fragments")` to your activity's `onSavedInstanceState()` and launch gallery and process `onActivityResult()` from the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Using an `Intent` is not the way how to do it, because of the limitation of 1024kb per `Bundle`.
See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles

You could either a) save the image to file-system and only pass back the file-name (to be preferred) or b) add a custom`Application` class (which is always present) and then exchange the data by setting a `static` field in there, from where it then can be obtained again.

Comment: Is there any possible way to do this using an `Intent`? Everything seems to work fine for me when adding a new entry or editing one that doesn't already have an image attached to it regardless of image size, and I get this error right after the intent opens (before picking an image). 
If it isn't, I'll definitely look into the options here!